# Drawing a PNG Image Into a Graphics Context for Blending Mode Manipulation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I need to draw a series of PNGs into a `CGContext` so I can blend them together:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
```

Currently I have my app working based on just drawing each image as a UIImageView and adding them as a subview to the view file via: `[self addSubview:someImageView]` ...but this doesn't allow for blending mode manipulation, right?

Currently the UIImageView vars are being assigned via:

```
someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name.png"]];
```

So I've tried replacing those with either of these with no luck:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name.png"] drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
```

and this one needs a `CGImage` which I'm not sure how to make with the PNGs:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, someCGImage);
```

So what am I missing? These aren't being triggered by any interaction, they just need to load/draw when the app loads.

Thanks for any leads. :)

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to be using UIImageViews.
Instead, bracket your drawing between calls to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.

For example (code not tried):

```
UIImage* uiimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name.png"];
UIImage* uiimage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"other-image-name.png"];

CGSize size = uiimage.size; 

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[uiimage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
[uiimage2 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];

UIImage* blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If you want to use CG calls, call:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

to get the context ref.

Comment: BTW, it's easy to make a CGImage from a UIImage. There is  CGImage property on UIImage. However, avoiding mixing UIImage and CGImage drawing routines, or else you'll find that the drawing context is upside-down.

Comment: I wasn't clear on that last part, as I want to rotate the uiimages before drawing them, but calling CGContextRotateCTM(context, 3.14); before the drawing command didn't actually rotate by the desired 180 degrees.

And yes, the first command I called in the drawRect method was CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it right. Can you post your new code?