# More memory efficient way of displaying images in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a photo collage app that takes a bunch of photos from a user's facebook/instagram/library, and draws a bunch of them onto the UIView. To control the amount, there is a slider tool that calculates density (for example, every 150px wide, add an image). I'm running into memory issues after lots and lots of UIImageViews are being added.

Is there some better, more efficient way of showing images onto the screen?

Comment: do you show all these images on the screen at the same time? and how are you showing these images, is it scrollview? add more information please

Comment: Yes, its essentially a bunch of UIImageViews added to a single UIView. I subclass the UIImageViews and add touch gesture so they can be rotated, pinched, dragged.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a `UICollectionView`.  It's designed to present a group of objects (including images) in a manner similar to `UITableVIew`.  Like a TableView memory is automatically managed by the controller.

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

You didn't make it clear in your question exactly how you're using this set of images.  An alternative is to draw the images into the graphic context using Core Graphics.  This will draw the images into a single view instead of into several views.  There's only one bitmap to keep in memory.  See [Drawing a PNG Image Into a Graphics Context for Blending Mode Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936644/drawing-a-png-image-into-a-graphics-context-for-blending-mode-manipulation) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way I'm using the UIImageView is basically splattering a bunch of photos onto the screen, letting the user drag drop and resize them until their happy. I don't think UICollectionView would be appropriate, but your other suggestion may be useful and will look into it. Thanks!