# How to put together an "image" of images in a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use several CALayers as sublayers of an UIViewController.
The first one is a background.

The others are in front of this background.

How do i put together/draw an Image with holes/transparent spots
and draw that in a CALayer so the background is still visible.

I don't want to use a CALayer for every Image, i would end up with 20 000 CALayers or more...

So how to put together an "image" of images in a CALayer ? (which is then used as a sublayer)

Code example:

```
// rootView which is a UIViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _sproutLayer = [[CGSproutLayer alloc] initWithLayer:[CALayer layer]];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_sproutLayer];
    [_sproutLayer setZPosition:1];
    [_sproutLayer setNeedsDisplay];

    _backgroundLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    CGRect positionOne = CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 150);
    _backgroundLayer.frame = positionOne;
    _backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    _backgroundLayer.name = @"One";
    _backgroundLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"].CGImage;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_backgroundLayer];
    [_backgroundLayer setZPosition:0];
    [_backgroundLayer setNeedsDisplay];

    _refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(doIterate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)doIterate:(NSTimer *)timer
{    
    [self.something doComputeStuff];
    ...
    [_sproutLayer draw];
}

// CGSproutLayer which is a CALAyer
- (void)draw 
{   
    int cellSize = self.bounds.size.width / WIDTH;
    double xOffset = 0;

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);
    NSUInteger cellIndex = 0;
    cellFrame.origin.x = xOffset;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++)
        {         
                NSNumber *currentCell = [self.levelState.board objectAtIndex:cellIndex];                 
                if (currentCell.intValue == sprouts)
                {
                    [image1 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                }
                else if (currentCell.intValue == grass)
                {
                    [image2 drawInRect:cellFrame];
                }       
            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: The iPhone has 960*640 pixels which is about 600000 pixels in total. That is about 30 pixels per layer. We are talking pixels still so the amount of points would be a quarter of that (7 or 8 points). That is for example 2x4 points on screen. Nothing that small is going to be useful. **What could you possibly do with that many layers on screen at once?**

Comment: Thats why i said i dont want to use 20 000 CALayers. I rephrase: If i have a skull as a background how do i draw the hair on top of it. I could reuse a single CALayer which resembles a piece of hair or somehow put together a big image of hair which is transparent so i can still see the skull. But how to accomplish this ?

Comment: You're going to want to draw all of your images to a separate context, then create a blended UIImage from that context. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1936644/1592655) post for an example. Note: if you wish to use the main context, you must do your call within a `DrawRect()`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like sethHB suggested :
This solution is VERY fast and sufficient for the amount of images i suggested above.

```
- (void)draw 
{
    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellSize, cellSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {
        cellFrame.origin.y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++, cellIndex++)
        {
                CGPoint pp = CGPointMake(i, j);
                if (currentCell.intValue == sprouts)
                {
                    [image1 drawAtPoint:pp blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];                 
                }
                else if (currentCell.intValue == grass)
                {
                    [image2 drawAtPoint:pp blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];                    
                } 
            }
            cellFrame.origin.y += cellSize;
        }
        cellFrame.origin.x += cellSize;
    }
    UIImage* blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    _frontLayer.contents = (id) blendedImage.CGImage;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Thank you SethHB !